# Failed to create table: Error while reading data, error message: Input file is not in Parquet format

Tags: google-bigquery, gzip, parquet

Trying to load a `*.parquet.gz` file as Parquet in BigQuery I get this issue.

Isn't Bigquery supposed to recognize that this is a compressed parquet file?

When I decompress it and load it as `.parquet` it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compressing a parquet with gzip defeats most of the benefits of Parquet columnar compression and reduces our ability to process or parallelize the import.

What BigQuery supports is [compression of data blocks on parquet](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-parquet#parquet_compression) not the whole file itself.

Comment: Good point.. That’s how we are receiving data from Clevertap unfortunately, will need to unzip before loading..